# Im getting an error in python when working with sockets and threards

Tags: python, sockets

server.py :

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64

PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length.decode(FORMAT))
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

client.py:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'

PORT = 5050
SERVER = '***.***.***.**'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_lenght = len(message)
    send_lenght = str(msg_lenght).encode(FORMAT)
    send_lenght += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_lenght))
    client.send(send_lenght)
    client.send(message)

send("Hello World!")
```

Every time i run `client.py` i get this error in `server.py` :

```
[STARTING] Server is starting...
[LISTENING] Server is listening on ***.***.**
[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] 1
[NEW CONNECTION] ('***.***.***', 60096) connected.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\workspace\Learn\Python\Sokets\server.py", line 24, in handle_client
    msg = conn.recv(msg_length.decode(FORMAT))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is shown for this line

```
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length.decode(FORMAT))
```

It should be this instead, i.e. the decoding should be done on the result from `recv` not on the `msg_length` given as argument to `recv`.

```
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
```